# What does 'frozen distribution' mean in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

In the documentation of scipy, the 'frozen pdf', etc, is mentioned sometimes, but I don't know the meaning  of it? Is it a statistical concept or scipy terminology?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that the docs are somewhat unclear on the issue. It seems that the frozen distribution fixes the first `n` moments for programmer's convenience. I am unaware of the term "forzen distribution" outside of SciPy.

SciPy's frozen distribution is perhaps best described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#freezing-a-distribution):

> Passing the loc and scale keywords time and again can become quite
>   bothersome. The concept of freezing a RV is used to solve such
>   problems.
>
> `rv = gamma(1, scale=2.)`
>
> By using rv we no longer have to include the scale or the shape
>   parameters anymore. Thus, distributions can be used in one of two
>   ways, either by passing all distribution parameters to each method
>   call (such as we did earlier) or by freezing the parameters for the
>   instance of the distribution. Let us check this:
>
> `rv.mean(), rv.std() (2.0, 2.0)`
>
> This is, indeed, what we should get.

In the scipy tutorial page, we see the following line:

> (We explain the meaning of a frozen distribution below).

The only mention of frozen distribution after that point is the following:

> The main additional methods of the not frozen distribution are related
>   to the estimation of distribution parameters:
>
> ```
> fit: maximum likelihood estimation of distribution parameters, including location
>
>     and scale
>
> fit_loc_scale: estimation of location and scale when shape parameters are given
>
> nnlf: negative log likelihood function
>
> expect: calculate the expectation of a function against the pdf or pmf
> ```

Comment: All of the `scipy.stats` docs are "somewhat unclear", but yes, "frozen" is probably the high point.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

In the book Haslwanter, T. (2016). An introduction to statistics with Python. With Applications in the Life Sciences; Springer International Publishing: Cham, Switzerland.  In the page 99, the Author tell us:

"In the first step, you create the distribution (e.g., nd = stats.norm() ). Note that this is a distribution (in Python parlance a 'frozen distribution'), not a function yet!"

Then, a frozen distribution simply not is a function.